# При открытии файла из VS code через live server открывается редактор Ckeditor вместо страницы в браузере

Tags: javascript, php, html, visual-studio-code

Подскажите в чем или с чем может быть проблема. Открываю с VS Code файл index.html в Live Server и отображается редактор Ckeditor (пример прилагаю). Изначально вообще открывался каталог папок и файлов, но после установки php на комп, стал открываться Ckeditor и на самой страничке на какие бы кнопки не нажимала, не срабатывает.
Я новичок, с таким ещё не сталкивалась, не могу понять в чем дело, в интеренете не нашла подобных случаев.
Как исправить, чтобы открылась страничка сайта?
[image: пример]

Comment: Попробуйте указать, какой программой открывать файлы `.html` по умолчанию в самой ОС (в Windows правой кнопкой мыши по файлу html -> Свойства)

Comment: Спасибо, к сожалению не помогло. По умолчанию было установлен IE, изменила на Chrome. Перезапустила VS Code, заново попробовала открыть, та же картина((